# How to configure authentication properly for a multi-tenant application in wildfly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a multi-tenant java-ee application which I am running on wildfly. For authentication I have a custom LoginModule configured in my security-domain configuration.

I am facing a couple of issues.

Scenario 1 : cache-type set to default

1. User with name "foo" logs in for tenant1. In this case the LoginModule's login method is invoked.
2. User with name "foo" logs in for tenant2. In this case the LoginModule's login method is NOT invoked.

This is a big problem because now the tenant2 user is logged in essentially as a tenant1 user and has similar privileges.

Scenario 2 : cache-type not set

In this scenario things work properly as far as the end user is concerned. However there is a problem. For every request that is made now the LoginModule.login method is invoked.

My question is what is the proper way to set up authentication on wildfly for a multi-tenant application.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd set `cache-type` to `default`, but force a [logout](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-logout-example) for the user before he tries to log in again.